# HTML parser is returning null instead of errors after parsing the html string

Tags: html, angular

I am parsing HTML string, for validation check, I am removing closing tags in the HTML, then The parsing errors are getting NULL when I give Type as "text/html".

For Reference adding the code:
Basic HTML,
here for "p" tag I removed closing brace

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {color:red;}
p {color:blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p

</body>
</html>
```

For parsing this HTML, below code is used, here this.code is html

```
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(this.code, "text/html");
    const errorNode = doc.querySelector('parsererror');
```

here errorNode is getting NULL, even after removing that closing brace for "p" tag.
[image: errorNode NULL]

for the same code, if I keep Type as "application/xml",
I am getting this in the errorNode
[image: errorNode message]

Comment: The HTML parser is _meant_ to be highly fault-tolerant. If it finds errors it can silently "fix" on its own, then it will do so.

Comment: Yes, you can verify that by looking into the childnodes of body within the generated htmdocument, it recognizes the paragraph and closes it correctly